# Add whitespaces inside option element reactjs airbnb

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Which one is the best approach to add spaces before an option element in react?

I am using this way:

[image]

I am using airbnb js styleguide, The ESLint alert says `[eslint]`   `must be placed on a new line [react/jsx-one-expression-per-line]`

So I don't know which one should be the approach that I have to use, I have tried lot of ways, but no one works.

Comment: Cleaner way would to store an object in ```data``` & parse into HTML afterwards. Storing full HTML increases the size of ```data```.

Comment: This question is opinion based, there is no specific correct answer. Therefore, this question is offtopic.